# How to list all available AWS instances with boto/python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to list all the ec2 available type instances in the region where i deploy. I would like to use python/boto if this is possible. If not, then REST API.

(I search very old questions, and they said this was not implemented yet. did this change ?)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list all available instance types in boto3 by using the [describe_instance_types](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instance_types) method.

This will return the instance types available, along with their configuration options.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)